# Convert ARRAY_UPPER() to Hive query

Tags: sql, postgresql, hive

I have to convert a postgres query to a hive query as :

```
Select
SUBSTRING(col_name[ARRAY_UPPER(col_name)][2],1,8)
from tab
```

As hive does not have anything called ARRAY_UPPER then how can we covert?
In my hive table corresponding col_name is of String type, so I tried as below but not getting desired output.

```
select substring(col_name,-10,8) from hive_tab
```

Input and output are:
[image]

Comment: Please, could you put an example of data input and data output.

Answer (score 0):

```
with data_example as(
select 
array(1476290200, 35525707293822) as a
)

select substr(a[size(a)-1],-7)
  from data_example
```

Result:

```
7293822
```